# Polygon pour in polygon cutout?

Tags: pcb, altium, design, polygon

I'm designing a 4 layer board in Altium Designer 20.0.1 with an STM32F103RBT6 and am doing the 8MHz and 32kHz crystal layouts. According to the recommended layout each crystal is supposed to have a ground plane beneath them, a small gap around between the crystal grounds and the ground plane and have a single trace connecting them. The second layer from top is GND and I made a Polygon cutout. I then made the separate ground polys for the crystals but they won't fill. I can see the border of the polygon but they won't fill. I suspect it won't fill because I have a poly cutout and then planes in the cutout but I can't figure how to get i to work.
[image]

Comment: Why did you make a cutout in layer 2 - it doesn't seem clear why you should. Are you sure you have read the instructions correctly?

Comment: The cutout is needed if the pour and the components are on the same layer. The components are on the top layer but the cutout is on one of the mid layers. No need to place a cutout.

Comment: I think I got it right according to this pdf: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00221665-oscillator-design-guide-for-stm8afals-stm32-mcus-and-mpus-stmicroelectronics.pdf  (page 42, point 5). Cutout on all layers, and then each crystal get's its local ground on layer 2 connected to the whole ground layer by a single trace.